# Displaying images in popup menus in Emacs

Tags: image, emacs, popup, elisp, emacs24

I'm working on an Emacs mode for people learning Japanese. The point is to help them learn the stroke orders of various Japanese characters (especially kanji) by running a set of functions which extract the character at point and if it is a Japanese character, displaying an image with the stroke order. I have worked out almost all the details, but I have a question about displaying images. I'd like to be able to display the image object (obtained by `create-image`) in a popup menu anchored at point. Any hints on doing that? Alternatively I'd like to create a new temporary buffer displaying the image. I've tried using `insert-image` with the image object, but all I see in the resulting buffer is an empty rectangle where the image should be. How can I make a buffer with a visible image? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to put images in popup menus.  What does your `insert-image` call look like?  Evaluating the following in the scratch buffer inserts an image into the buffer for me: `(insert-image (create-image "img-0080.png"))`

Comment: @legoscia, it works in *scratch*. Is this the question of enabling some mode in the newly created buffer?

Comment: It should just work... If you hit `C-u C-x =` over the empty rectangle, what does it show for the "display" property?

Comment: `display              (image :type png :file "kanji-png/08a00.png")`
yet no image is displayed in my buffer...

Comment: Hm, that's a relative path. Perhaps the current directory is different in this buffer.  Could you try making the image path absolute with `expand-file-name`?

Comment: Haha, great. That was it. Thanks very much, @legoscia! BTW, any idea about displaying images in a popup menu?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. The elisp manual suggests using `:image` in "menu items" when they are actually tool bar items - but I suspect most toolkits wouldn't actually display the images in a popup menu.

Answer (score 5):

Putting an image in a tooltip might help, as a start.

I do that in [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus) -- see the code for `diredp-mouseover-help` and `diredp-image-dired-create-thumb`.  This is the core of it:

- Unless `image-dired-thumb-name` says there is already a thumbnail for the image file, use `image-dired-create-thumb` to create one.  This is the main part of `diredp-image-dired-create-thumb`.
- Display either the full image or a thumbnail in a tooltip on mouseover:

```
    (let ((img-file  (if (eq 'full diredp-image-preview-in-tooltip)
                         file
                       (diredp-image-dired-create-thumb file))))
      (propertize " " 'display (create-image img-file)))
```

A next step could be to put a `keymap` or `local-map` property on the image, with, say, a `mouse-1` binding that acts as the choice action for that image choice.  Just a thought - haven't tried it.

You would presumably want to put multiple images in the same tooltip, each with a different action function. Haven't tried that, but you might experiment.

HTH.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to get an image in a kind of "popup at point" using a toltip-frame as the popup, and then only if you built Emacs with "non-toolkit tooltips".  I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` requesting some way to do that.  It shouldn't be too hard to implement, e.g. by providing access to the "non-toolkit tooltips" even when compiled with a toolkit.  Other Elisp libraries could probably make use of such a functionality (e.g. company-mode).